# Error with tk.Frame configurating in class

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing simple GUI witch contains 5 screens.
I want to configure basic class (`tk.Frame`) and set options like geometry, resizable, bg, etc. How can i manage this in my code?

```
class FormApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, *kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.configure('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (XRes,YRes,
                (ClientWidth-XRes)/2,
                (ClientHeight-YRes)/2-20))
        container.self.resizable(0, 0)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree, PageFour, PageFive):
            frame=F(container, self)
            self.frames[F]=frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
```

I got errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Vladimir/Desktop/python/!project/Five Windows.py", line 113, in <module>
    app = FormApp()   File "C:/Users/Vladimir/Desktop/python/!project/Five Windows.py", line 37, in __init__
    (ClientHeight-YRes)/2-20))   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1472, in _configure
    return self._getconfigure1(_flatten((self._w, cmd, '-'+cnf)))   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1460, in _getconfigure1
    x = self.tk.splitlist(self.tk.call(*args))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-700x960+610+40"
```

Doesn't the string

```
 container.configure('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (XRes,YRes,
            (ClientWidth-XRes)/2,
            (ClientHeight-YRes)/2-20))
```

configure container?

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn`t the string
>
> `container.configure('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (XRes,YRes,
>               (ClientWidth-XRes)/2,
>               (ClientHeight-YRes)/2-20))`
>
> configure container?'

No, it does not. `.configure` is the way to configure the widget, but the first argument must be one of the configurable options (`background`, `borderwidth`, etc).

If you're trying to set the width and height of the frame, you need to configure the `width` and `height` options.

If you're trying to set the size of the main window, you need to call the `geometry` method on the root window instance. In your specific case it would be `self.geometry(...)`.